# How check string if he contains at least 1 number or 1 letter?

Tags: php, regex

How can I ensure a string contains at least 1 number or 1 letter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$valid = preg_match('/[\pL\pN]/U', $str);

$strs = array(
   'привет', // TRUE
   'hello',  // TRUE
   '42',     // TRUE
   '%'       // FALSE
);
```

[Check it](http://ideone.com/4XM6w).

Comment: Yay for Unicode, but please remove the anchors, or only a string that is exactly 1 character long will match.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Whoops, don't know how they snuck in there!

Comment: Thanks!What about upper case?

Comment: @Yose It will handle uppercase. `\pL` includes uppercase letters.

Answer (score 3):

```
$contains = preg_match('~[\da-z]~i', $str)
```

Comment: You should add `/i` to make it case insensitive. Otherwise it would not work with uppercase letters.

Comment: So `(Ä)!` is not a valid string?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: yes, yes, I already discussed with Alex about his great utf-compilant solution ;-)